# How to handle panorama items in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I'm having three panorama items, what I want to do is that when one item in being viewed, i want the next item which is partiaally visible to be dim (i.e it looks like being disabled).
How can i do that??

Answer (score 0):

There is a [SelectionChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893053/how-to-use-panorama-item-selectionchanged) event. So you can handle this event to change [`VisualState`](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-working-with-visualstates-how-to-make-a-toggleswitch-from-checkbox) of your panorama items.